# How to make button on click listener in fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to set an `onClickListener` on a button, but I am facing a problem.

I can't get the `context` I need after the button is clicked.
I tried by `view` but didn't work, it doesn't work but also doesn't throw an error.

The xml file in fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="go to test" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java fragment code :

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Objects;


public class Homefragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

Button test;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

       test = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.test);

       test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               System.out.println("Clicked go to test");
               Toast.makeText(getContext(), "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               Intent gotest;
               gotest = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),testing.class);
               startActivity(gotest);

           }
       });

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,null);
    }
}
```

My logcat gives no error and I use print command when the button is clicked but print does not work, like if the button is not clicked.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice

Comment: Instead `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,null);` there should be `return view;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this return your view.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

   test = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.test);

   test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           System.out.println("Clicked go to test");
           Toast.makeText(getContext(), "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           Intent gotest;
           gotest = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),testing.class);
           startActivity(gotest);

       }
   });
   return view;
}
```

Comment: Alternativly, use onViewCreated, and use getView()